# Why is my Swift loop failing with error "Can't form range with end < start"?

Tags: swift, for-loop, runtime-error, factors

I have a for loop that checks if a number is a factor of a number, then checks if that factor is prime, and then it adds it to an array.  Depending on the original number, I will get an error saying

> fatal error: Can't form range with end < start

This happens almost every time, but for some numbers it works fine.  The only numbers I have found to work with it are 9, 15, and 25.

Here is the code:

```
let num = 16 // or any Int
var primes = [Int]()

for i in 2...(num/2) {

    if ((num % i) == 0) {
        var isPrimeFactor = true

        for l in 2...i-1 {
            if ((i%l) == 0) {
                isPrimeFactor = false;
            }//end if
        }//end for

        if (isPrimeFactor == true) {
            primes.append(i)
        }//end if

    }//end if

}//end for
```

Answer (score 72):

## Swift 5

If you need a loop with dynamic value-range, I suggest that using `stride(to:by:)` instead of `..<` or `...`

Basically `..<` or `...` will be crashed if `start_index > end_index`.

This will be crash:

```
let k = 5
for i in 10...k { print("i=\(i)") }
for i in 10..<k { print("i=\(i)") }
```

How to fix:

```
let k = 5
for i in stride(from: 10, through: k, by: 1) { print("i=\(i)") }
for i in stride(from: 10, to: k, by: 1) { print("i=\(i)") }
```

***NOTE:***

The code above *won't print out anything*, but it won't be crash when execution.

Also, if you want to stride from a *higher* number to a *lower* number then the `by` parameter needs to be changed to a **negative** number.

Reference:

- http://michael-brown.net/2016/using-stride-to-convert-c-style-for-loops-to-swift-2.2/
- http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/Strideable/

Comment: "by" parameter must be (-1) or nothing will be printed

Comment: @igrrik: Please read carefully. We are talking about the fatal error cause by ..< and how to fix it. Run two block codes above separate and you will see.

Answer (score 9):

In your second loop, `i` will always start at 2, which means you're looping from `2...1`

Comment: But how come it works with some numbers and not others?

Comment: those three numbers are odd so the `num % i` condition is false.

Comment: So how would I fix this? If i start it at 1 then it doesn't add anything to "primes"

Comment: Man in any normal programming language and you write `for(...;lowerBound<upperBound;...)` the condition is false on entering the loop and the whole loop is passed. This situation is absolutely normal. But swift is so silly that can't understand it and you need additional conditions and/or another loop syntax

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov because `0..<n` syntax creates a `CountableRange` object, which has a (quite reasonable) precondition. You could say `let myRange = 0..<5`, and perform a bunch of operations on it; many of which would be nonsense if not for this precondition. It's not just "the language can't understand what I'm saying." Syntax and semantics are completely different than the C-style for loop.

Answer (score 6):

**SWIIFT 4**

The best way to go is to use stride as by this documentation page: 
[Generic Function stride(from:to:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride)

`for i in stride(from: 10, through: 5, by: -1) { print(i) }`

and stride through if you want to include the lowerBound: [Generic Function stride(from:through:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641185-stride)

Answer (score 5):

Both `ClosedRange` and `CountableRange` throw this error unless `start <= end`.  One problem with using `stride(from:to:by)` is that it returns a `Strideable` and not a `Range`, which doesn't work with the "is in range" operator `~=`.  To handle these cases, I use an extension which gives me a bounds-safe range, where invalid ranges become an empty range:

```
extension Int {
  func until(_ end: Int) -> CountableRange<Int> {
    return self <= end ? self..<end : self..<self
  }

  func through(_ end: Int) -> CountableRange<Int> {
    return self <= end ? self..<(end + 1) : self..<self
  }
}
```

Both return `CountableRange` so that an invalid `through` range becomes an empty range. (Side note: the name `until` is chosen because this "safe" range behaves the same as `until` ranges in Kotlin/Android).

Usage:

```
for i in 0.until(3) { /* do something */ }

let printRange = { (range: Range<Int>) -> Void in
  for i in range {
    print(i, terminator: " ")
  }
  print()
}
printRange(0.until(3))  // prints "0 1 2"
printRange(0.until(0))  // prints ""
printRange(3.until(0))  // prints ""
printRange(0.through(3))  // prints "0 1 2 3"
printRange(0.through(0))  // prints "0"
printRange(3.through(0))  // prints ""
print(0.until(1) ~= -1)  // prints "false"
print(0.until(1) ~= 0)  // prints "true"
print(0.until(1) ~= 1)  // prints "false"
print(0.until(0) ~= 0)  // prints "false"
print(1.until(0) ~= 0)  // prints "false"
print(0.through(1) ~= -1)  // prints "false"
print(0.through(1) ~= 0)  // prints "true"
print(0.through(1) ~= 1)  // prints "true"
print(0.through(0) ~= 0)  // prints "true"
print(1.through(0) ~= 0)  // prints "false"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use range where upperBound < lowerBound, you can add reversed() to it.

for eg: `for number in (0...highestPossibleNumber).reversed()`

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple solution you can make for loop reverse using Stride and -

```
func reverseArray(oldarray: [String]) -> [String] {
        var newArray = [String]()
        let len = oldarray.count
        for i in stride(from: len - 1, through: 0, by: -1)
        {    newArray.append(oldarray[i])
            print(i)
        }
        return newArray
    }

input :  print(reverseArray(oldarray: ["World", "Hello"]))

output : ["Hello", "World"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to apply ".reversed()" to your array.
Example: array.reversed()