# What is the nil or "empty" countable range in Swift?

Tags: swift3, iteration, control-flow

In Swift3,

```
let highestIndex = 7
for index in 1 ..< highestIndex {
    latter(index)
}
```

however,

```
let highestIndex = 0, or anything smaller
for index in 1 ..< highestIndex {
    latter(index)
}
```

that crashes.

So, the ..< operator is impractical in most situations.

So, perhaps, something like this ...

```
for index in (1 ..< highestIndex).safely() {
    latter(index)
}
```

How would one write the extension `safely` ?

Or at worst just a function `safely(from,to)` which returns a CountableRange, or, an "empty" (?) countable range? (I don't understand if a Swift extension can "catch" an error?)

Comment: "*Is there such a thing as an "empty" countable range*" – yes, `1..<1` is just that (it does not crash).

Comment: If you don't want the loop to be entered if the upper bound is less than the lower bound, `stride` is a good alternative – see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/36861439/2976878

Comment: [DOH facepalm](http://cdn.onegreenplanet.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/2014/11/lead1.jpg)  -- **stride**, of course, that's the way to go.  you've cracked it again, @Hamish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a fan of simple solutions:

```
let lowerIndex = 1
let higherIndex = 0
for index in lowerIndex ..< max(lowerIndex, higherIndex) {
    latter(index)
}
```

Comment: agreed - KISS.  I guess, one could just put that in a custom infix operator, and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Sticking as closely to the `..<` operator as possible the following would be an appropriate implementation of `safely`.

```
public func safely<Bound>(_ minimum: Bound, _ maximum: Bound) -> CountableRange<Bound> where Bound : _Strideable & Comparable, Bound.Stride : Integer {
    if maximum < minimum {
        return CountableRange(uncheckedBounds: (lower: minimum, upper: minimum))
    }
    return CountableRange(uncheckedBounds: (lower: minimum, upper: maximum))
}

let one = safely(0, 12)  // CountableRange(0..<12)
let two = safely(15, 12) // CountableRange(15..<15)

one.isEmpty // false
two.isEmpty // true
```

You might want to consider giving the parameters better names to indicate wether or not they are inclusive / exclusive bounds, etc.

Creating an extension and adding a `.safely()` will not work since the bounds are checked when creating the `CountableRange` before the call to `safely` could even be done.

Comment: Say, in your excellent code.  I'd suggest, the first return should just be "return 0..<0".  Emphasizing the fact that you're just returning "no trips".  Great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to get this to work fine:

```
for index in 1 ..< 1 {
    latter(index)
}
```

For the `<1` case, I recommend something like this:

```
guard highestIndex > 0 else { return }

for index in 1 ..< highestIndex {
    latter(index)
}
```

Comment: Hey Mark - thanks for that.  Sure, "guard" is a terrific feature. But, you know, it's no good for inline code; the most natural situation is that of course, you just want it to "not do any iterations" if the value is too low....